# oracle sql(missing left parenthesis

Tags: database, oracle

Im trying to create a table named grad_candidates

```
  CREATE TABLE grad_candidates
    (student_id    NUMBER(6),
    last_name VARCHAR2,
    first_name VARCHAR2,
    credits NUMBER(3),
    graduation_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE);
```

ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis,, Can anyone help??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VARCHAR2` requires a numerical bound to go with it, for example:

```
last_name VARCHAR2(30),
```

So, change your code to:

```
 CREATE TABLE grad_candidates
    (student_id  NUMBER(6),
    last_name VARCHAR2 (255),
    first_name VARCHAR2 (255),
    credits NUMBER(3),
    graduation_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE);
```

[Learn more about the create table syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm)

Comment: Thank you,, but now when I try and view the table it says no data found

Comment: Anyone know why I can't view the table with SELECT * FROM grad_candidates?

Comment: @Yoyoyo Open up *another* question and give all the details you can. Thanks.